# Application development in Go

Tags: go, package, business-logic-layer

I'm writing a web application in Go. So far I've written all base libraries I'm going to need for now and that worked out just perfect. The package structure is really handy in that aspect.

Now I'm at the point where I need to start writing the application itself, the business logic.  I'm a little lost of how or *where* this code should go.

I've watched and read pretty much every application development tutorial/walkthrough on the official documentation page and they always write the entire domain logic in the `main` package/namespace.

Is this *the way to Go* (sorry, had to) or was it just for the sake of simplicity?

Putting the business layer into packages feels uncomfortably wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not have to be all in the same package. You can easily make a new directory, put your code for that package there, and import it from your `main` package. It's simple as that.

You may want to look at [`go-tour`](http://code.google.com/p/go-tour/) as a simple web app that consists of a few small packages (`pic`, `wc`, ...). If you want to see organization of a big Go app see [Camlistore](http://camlistore.org/). Both of these are written by Go Authors, so they can be considered nice examples.

I just have to say that writing small, reusable, and separate packages is very common in Go, and that reduces the size of the main codebase of apps.

Comment: You should also take a look at gorilla, a web toolkit for go that provide  independent package for routine, sessions, ... http://gorilla-web.appspot.com/

Comment: Indeed Gorilla is a great toolkit and I'm a user and a fan. But what does it have to do with this question?

Comment: Thought it was worth mentioning to someone starting go web application development, maybe I should have commented his question instead of your answer :)